# Insert or update on duplicate values with wrong indexes

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table structure:

```
id  | partner_id | client_id | key | value
111   1            2           key   old_value
```

I want to insert new values to it, and update the value without inserting if the `partner_id`, `client_id`, and `key` are the same. What I have right now is:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('222', '1', '2', 'key', 'new_value')
ON CONFLICT (partner_id, client_id, key)
SET value = 'new_value';
```

The problem is that the indexes are not correct, I have three:

```
PRIMARY id
UNIQUE partner_id
FOREIGN client_id
```

Will this query always work correctly, even with those indexes?